# Remove URL regardless of format

Tags: php

Having a brain freeze...

Have a URL which may be in any of the formats :

```
http://url.com/stuff
url.com/somestuff
www.url.com/otherstuff
https://www.url.com/morestuff
```

You get the picture.

How do I remove the .com part to leave just the various 'stuff' parts ? For example, the above would end up :

```
stuff
somestuff
otherstuff
morestuff
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: Still looking through the answers. I think I've learnt that I need to be more specific with my questions... The 'stuff' part can contain any number of characters including another / . All the answers are great (although parse_url needs a version of PHP which I'm not using I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick for you!

```
<?php
$url = "http://url.com/stuff";

$querystring = preg_replace('#^(https|http)?(://)?(www.)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/#', "", $url);

echo $querystring;
```

I submitted this answer because I'm not very fond of solutions using `explode()` to handle this. Maybe your query string contains more slashes so, you'd have to write exceptions for those cases.

Comment: THanks for that. This works perfect for what I wanted to do. (sorry to others because I wasn't clear in the question)

Comment: Actually, this doesn't quite work. You need to swap the https and http around because it seems to be greedy on the http

Comment: I fixed that now. Try it again to see if still does that

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve that using the following code:

```
$com_pos      = strpos($url, '.com/');
$stuff_part   = substr($url, $com_pos + 5);
```

Click [here](http://codepad.org/JnVIPpdn) to see the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to make an array, then get the last element from the array.

```
$str = 'http://url.com/stuff';
$arr = explode('/', $str);
echo end($arr); // 'stuff'
```

Comment: @RobertPitt: The OP's example did not contain URLs with more than one string after the `.com`, so this solution matches the OP's example.

Comment: he obviously wanted the URI of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/^(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+/" ,"", $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = parse_url('http://url.com/stuff', PHP_URL_PATH);
```

If you leave the second parameter unspecified you can return an array including the domain etc.

Comment: Also make sure your string is always prepended with the protocol (e.g., http:// https:// ftp://)

Comment: And don't forget to strip the first character, which should be a forward slash!

Answer (score 0):

Use explode function to divide the string.

```
<?php
$url = "http://url.com/stuff";
$stuff = explode("/", $url);
echo $stuff[sizeof($stuff) - 1];
?>
```

I used sizeof to access to last element.